# How can I follow the development of a python standard lib module?

Tags: python, version-control

Let's say I am using a selected handful of python standard library modules in some very important code.

How can I follow the development of said modules? If it were other python libs, I would simply follow the changelog on git, but for standard modules I am quite lost.

Comment: Well, one thing working in your favor is that the Standard Library modules don't change that much.  While it's a great honor to be included in Python as a Standard Module, that honor also hamstrings the module's ability to change.  Hence the the epithet, "The Standard Library: where modules go to die."

Comment: This is more of a programmers.stackexchange.com question, although I'm not sure whether it's on topic there either. Why do you *need* to follow it? They'll only introduce new features with new Python releases, and they'll almost never break backward compatibility.

Comment: Well I don't really wish to follow python's releases development closely. For example, [this release](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/) lists a lot things I don't care about.
I was wondering if there was a simple way to follow a standard lib module.